# Экранирование тега <?php

Tags: php

Как стоит экранировать `<?php` ?
Например я хочу записать в файл

```
<?php echo 'Hello world'; ?>
```

Для этого я составляю строку `"<?php echo 'Hello world'; ?>"`

И тут у меня происходит что-то непонятное. PHP интерпретирует `<?` как php код и в итоге все ломается. В то же время [в песочнице все работает](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e368a516583233c9bd2e3e43a4e875814805b1aa).

Что я упустил? Почему это работает так и как это исправить?

p.s. Если разделяю < и ? (`"< ?php echo 'Hello world'; ?>"`) все срабатывает как должно, но это естественно меня не устраивает, потому что и создаваемый файл не будет считаться php сценарием.

Comment: Экранируйте вопросительный знак `\x3F`.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov это не работает

Comment: у меня работает `echo htmlspecialchars("<\x3Fphp echo 'hello' \x3F>");`

Comment: @TryCatch всё записывается корректно: <?php

$str = '<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>';

file_put_contents('test.php', $str);

Comment: @AlexanderZonov ваш код превращает знаки в html сущности. В тексте это выглядит иначе. Моя задача сгенерировать php код, а не html строку.

Comment: @Эдуард у меня тоже записывается нормально. Но при выводе (echo, var_dump...) происходит то, что я не могу понять. Стало интересно в чем причина и как это исправляется.

Comment: @TryCatch, превращает, но уже после того, как сформирована строка.  Я так написал, просто чтобы можно было быстрее увидеть результат на тесте.

Comment: @TryCatch а что вы хотите вывести? Покажите, что вы передаёте в  var_dump().

Comment: А какая версия PHP? Сейчас потестил, все работает в разных случаях без экранирования на 5.4, то есть проблемы не существует. Однако, я точно помню, что проблема из вашего вопроса когда-то была. Может, на старых версиях.

Comment: Спасибо всем кто проявил интерес к теме, проблема решена. Суть проблемы заключалась в том, что я выводил `echo "<?php echo 'Test'; ?>"` напрямую в браузер. Он считал что содержимое <...> это тег который не закрыт и закомментировал его (в случае `echo "<?php echo 'Test';"` было закомментировано все от < до первого >). Я просто не догадался посмотреть в исходный код. При выводе в textarea все стало понятно. @AlexanderZonov, в php существует другая проблема, с `?>` в конце строки. При определенных условиях это интерпретируется как конец сценария, проблему решают разбиением строки, видел на хабре.

Comment: PHP5.5. через echo\print ничего не выводит. в файл пишет нормально.
кажется автору  это и надо. просто не выводите, смотрите в файле))

Comment: @TryCatch точно!! оформите как ответ.  думаю кому то тоже будет интересно\полезно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем кто проявил интерес к теме, проблема решена.

Суть проблемы заключалась в том, что я выводил `echo "<?php echo 'Test'; ?>";` напрямую в браузер. Он считал что содержимое <...> это тег который не закрыт и комментировал его (в случае `echo "<?php echo 'Test';";` было закомментировано все от < до первого >).

Я не догадался посмотреть в исходный код. При выводе в textarea все стало понятно.

В php существует другая проблема, с `?>` в конце строки. При определенных условиях это интерпретируется как конец сценария. Из-за этого я и подумал что проблема именно в интерпретации.

Проблему решают разбиением строки, видел это где-то на хабре.